# Div Container CSS not being applied... Newbie

Tags: html, css, containers

HTML & CSS newbie can't work out why div container isn't being applied - I put the color as red to test it on the font - but it's not updating. I've named the container class as home.hero

I want to use a container for it, as I want to make text changes max width etc only affecting the text and not the background.

I am very bad at explaining this atm!

Thanks in advance (sorry for being a newb/noob/n00b)

P

```css
section#home {
    background: url('images/test.png') no-repeat center center/cover;;
    color: white;
    justify-content: left !important;
    padding: 8%;
    max-width: 60%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.home-hero {
  color: #E83C3C;
}
```

```html
<section id="home">
        <div class="home-hero">
          <h2 class="text-dark">Hello we are,</h2>
          <img src="images/test.png" alt="">
          <h2>Test <h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In molestie, augue vitae interdum rutrum, quam.</p>
        </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This is your output: https://nimb.ws/amYpsG The red color works. If it doesn't work then there is some other code working on it.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I moved it to the bottom of my CSS sheet as I have a number of other sections and pages and still no luck - so can't work out why these Div classes are being a problem. 

I had an issue with Div Containers earlier so instead of targeting the container, I targeted the element.

Comment: As a Sidenote, there is no reason to use `section#home` as a selector. `ID's` have to be unique. Therefor there should be only one element with that id in the first place. As such `#home` as selector would be the right way to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Your code does work for me, therefore I would suggest to you that makes sure that your css-link is correct.

You can in a lot of developer tools ctrl+click the css-link in the HTML file, and then you should be directed to the css-file. If you're directed to an undefined file or gets asked to create said css file, you know for sure that the file path in your html-document is wrong.

Note: css-link are in the head of the html-document and looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="aFolderHere/yourpage.css" type="text/css" />
```

or if your css is in the same directory/folder as your html is would look more like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourCSS.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the response FoxPaw really appreciate it! It's the correct link and you're right it appears to work elsewhere. 

Just not working in VScode - it's not being overwritten. Maybe I'll try closing VScode?! Might be something to do with Boostrap... 

Strange!

Comment: Just thought of something more, probably not it, but think just better safe than sorry.
You have not forgotten to save your css/html page and reload your browser?
And one additional note, could you post a screenshot of your result as well (from your browser)?

Comment: I made some changes and it seems to flipped a switch somewhere may have been overriden in the file somewhere. Seems to be all good now. 

Appreciate the response! Thank you FoxPaw!

Comment: @Patty, just glad it was solved =D. 
In that case, you should also be able to close this thread

Answer (score 0):

You have double semi-colons behind the first line in your css - this probably makes the browser stop reading past this point as it produces an error, so none of the remaining css is read:

```
section#home {
    background: url('images/test.png') no-repeat center center/cover;;
```

change to

```
section#home {
    background: url('images/test.png') no-repeat center center/cover;
```